Agreement between languages in $RE$
Say $L$ agrees with $L'$ if $\exists x \in \Sigma^{*}$ s.t $x \in L \iff x \in L'$.
Does there exist a language $L \in RE$ that agrees with any $L' \in RE$?

So thinking about general languages in $RE \cup coRE$ I thought $L' = L^c$ is a good counter example.
Thinking about languages in $RE$ got me thinking I must take $L=\Sigma^{*}$, but then I have a problem with $L' = \emptyset$.
Please help...

Since $\emptyset\in RE$, don't you have your counter-example already?

@Nathaniel I'm so sorry, I'm not sure i follow. The correct answer is that there is such a language. I don't understand which one or how to build it, and I'm sharing my thinking process.

$\emptyset \in RE$.
No language $L$ can agree with $\emptyset$, because $L\cap \emptyset = \emptyset$.
As such, there is no language $L\in RE$ that agrees with any $L'\in RE$.
